# I Get "object required" error when using getElementByID

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to enter a Username into a text box Using getElementById. this generates an "Object required" Error

```
Dim Myid
Mypsw As String
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ErrCnt

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

ChDir "C:\Users\hm_cl\Downloads"
Kill "History.txt"
Myid = "hmclark1959"
Mypsw = "xxxxxxxxx"

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://eteller.dakotalandfcu.com/Centryx/servlet/com.sos.webteller.accountaccess.LoginFrame"
While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
' ******** The following line generates the error
ie.document.getElementById("LoginID").Value = Myid

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox (Err.Description)

Select Case Err.Number
  Case 53  ' File not found
      Resume Next
  Case 424 ' Object Reuired
      ErrCnt = ErrCnt + 1
      If ErrCnt > 4 Then
        MsgBox (" Unknown Server Side Error")
        ie.Quit
        End
      Else
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
        Resume
      End If
  Case Else   'Unknown error
    MsgBox ("There is an unhandled error")
    ie.Quit
    End
End Select
```

When I click inspect element on the textbox it says the ID="LoginID"

Answer (score 0):

The page still runs in IE. But I give to consider, IE is actively being phased out by MS.

This is the html part in question

```html
<p id="LoginId">
  <label>Login Id</label>
  <input type="text" name="LoginId" maxlength="32" value="" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">
  <span class="checkdigit"></span>
</p>
```

As you see `LoginID` is the id of the p tag but you need the input tag to enter your text. The input tag is the first child and than the first sibling in the dom tree from the p tag. Try this:

```
ie.document.getElementById("LoginID").firstChild.nextSibling.Value = Myid
```

Look here for further information:
[firstChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp)
[nextSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp)
[Something about the Document Object Model (DOM)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I still get "Object required" Error

Comment: I have used this  code before, and it worked. Obviously on a different site. Some additional info. II am using VBA in Excel 365 with Windows 10Pro. The main problem is I have little understanding of HTML. Is there a better way to go about this.

Comment: The page cannot be accessed in any browser at the moment. So I can't try anything.